# How to set Json data to camelCase once on the client side

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, camelcasing

How does one go about turn serialized json data into camelCase data rather than all the properties upper case?

**In my View here is how I am turn the c# in Json**

```
team = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Employees));
```

**Here is the data: "All of this is Test data by the way"**

```
 team = [
    {
        "UserId": "902c2fe0-fcdf-4ed8-9591-5d8e01300cda",
        "UserName": "buderbits",
        "ID": 719,
        "Email": "erik@builder.com",
        "FName": "Builder",
        "LName": "Bits",
        "Title": "Glaizer",
        "Zip": "10027",
        "Phone": "456-768-9987",
        "AddressLine": "124 street st.",
        "City": "Nyc",
        "StateCD": "NY",
        "Avatar": "/users/RFyEQxDCpEavRfgDA028/qvzlezay.u1l.png",
        "RowNum": 3,
        "Total": 4,
        "IsDirty": false,
        "IsFlaggedForDelete": false,
        "SortOrder": 0
    },
    {
        "UserId": "a9cec535-ac48-4197-b8a0-87702cb14e52",
        "UserName": "stdard",
        "ID": 717,
        "Email": "erik@vinyl.org",
        "FName": "Erik",
        "LName": "Little",
        "Title": "Developer",
        "Zip": "75040",
        "Phone": "123-456-7890",
        "AddressLine": "123 Test Street",
        "City": "Garland",
        "StateCD": "TX",
        "Avatar": "/users/CZmP9uvdTCg8CdEhOAX0/kcm1yg2o.spn.gif",
        "RowNum": 1,
        "Total": 4,
        "IsDirty": false,
        "IsFlaggedForDelete": false,
        "SortOrder": 0
    },
    {
        "UserId": "1a4ef17a-9cd8-42e4-b172-3071e29a222a",
        "UserName": "teammber1",
        "ID": 2744,
        "Email": "erik2@erik.com",
        "FName": "Derick",
        "LName": "Mavrick",
        "Title": "Drafting",
        "Zip": "77702",
        "Phone": "111-111-1111",
        "AddressLine": "123 Teammember ST",
        "City": "Beaumont",
        "StateCD": "TX",
        "Avatar": "/users/rPF9z0a7yLJpp4e1Zb15/os1cmk0r.kkg.jpg",
        "RowNum": 4,
        "Total": 4,
        "IsDirty": false,
        "IsFlaggedForDelete": false,
        "SortOrder": 0
    },
    {
        "UserId": "17fab37f-d978-441c-a30d-8c08a7e6ce9b",
        "UserName": "stoontsoftware",
        "ID": 718,
        "Email": "support@storefront.net",
        "FName": "Mark",
        "LName": "Taylor",
        "Title": "Hosting",
        "Zip": "75070",
        "Phone": "345-432-1153",
        "AddressLine": "123 street dr",
        "City": "McKinney",
        "StateCD": "TX",
        "Avatar": "/users/y5TPPr0HR1GQLxkEhDuj/3bmwy0sk.qoi.png",
        "RowNum": 2,
        "Total": 4,
        "IsDirty": false,
        "IsFlaggedForDelete": false,
        "SortOrder": 0
    }
];
```

**HELP?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Newtonsoft's json serializer ([Json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)) which allows you to specify a formatter when serializing an object.

```
var d = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Employees, 
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
           ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        }));
console.log(d);
```

This will give you the lowercase property names for your js object/array created by the serialization.

Answer (score 0):

You could get your fields to camel case prior to sending to the client, by casting your initial query to a dynamic object or view model with camel-cased fields. For example, if the original query:

```
var model=db.Records.ToList();
```

produces your output, then modify your query to be:

```
var model=db.Records.Select(r=>
  new {firstName=r.FirstName,lastName=LastName, etc...).ToList();
```

To truly do it 100% on the client side, you would need to rebuild your table objects using a javascript method that replaces each object with a correctly-named object.

```
function NewObject(input){
    input=input||{};
    this.firstName=input.FirstName||'';
    this.lastName=input.LastName||'';
    ...etc.
}

var model=@Model; //your Json data as an object
for(var i=0;i<model.length;i++){
    model[i]=new NewObject(model[i]);
}
```